# why it is not wise to check -ENODEV for debugfs api

Tags: linux-kernel

debugfs api such as [debugfs_create_dir](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re465.html) said

> If debugfs is not enabled in the kernel, the value -ENODEV will be returned. It is not wise to check for this value, but rather, check for NULL or !NULL instead as to eliminate the need for #ifdef in the calling code.

But why is it not wise? Could you give me any examples about `eliminate the need for #ifdef in the calling code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may interpret -ENODEV as success, until doing with dentry returned something except deleting it(*debugfs_remove*) and using it as a directory for another file(*debugfs_create_*-family). All these functions process case, when CONFIG_DEBUG_FS is disabled, correctly.

That's why it is sufficient only for check NULL or !NULL.

In rare cases, when dentry returned by debugfs_create_*() is referred explicitely(e.g, for access inode's private data), it is sufficient to check, that only the first such call doesn't return -ENODEV.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. That advice makes no sense. If CONFIG_DEBUG_FS is not enabled, the value -ENODEV is returned (cast to a pointer). That is clearly not NULL, but also not usable as a valid pointer.

Better would be to instead use IS_ERR_OR_NULL(ptr) on the return value. If CONFIG_DEBUG_FS is not defined, this will catch -ENODEV return. If CONFIG_DEBUG_FS *is* defined, but the call fails, NULL is returned. This way handles either possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:
*"Could you give me any examples about eliminate the need for #ifdef in the calling code?"*

Well one way to write your code is:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_FS
  < ... do your debugfs stuff ... >
#endif
```

I would guess that that's what the documentation meant.

Many kernel devs consider putting too many `#ifdef - #endif` pairs in the code to be ugly ("hairy"). [See this kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Relevant snippet from the kernel Coding Style doc:
"Prefer to compile out entire functions, rather than portions of functions or
portions of expressions.  Rather than putting an ifdef in an expression, factor
out part or all of the expression into a separate helper function and apply the
conditional to that function."

Given that, following it's advice, if you would prefer *not* to use the #ifdef , then pl go with the answers already posted.

Comment: What confused me is why checking for NULL or !NULL is related to eliminate #ifdef. I may not explain it clearly. Thank you all the same.